# Convert mp3 to PCM

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I try to use aws amplify predictions.

The example is on this site on the end:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/predictions/transcribe/q/platform/js/#set-up-the-backend

```
    let buff = await file?.arrayBuffer()
    await Predictions.convert({
        transcription: {
            source: {
                bytes: buff

            }
        }
    }).then(({ transcription: { fullText } }) => console.log({ fullText }))
```

It says

> you can transcribe a PCM Audio byte buffer to Text, such as a
> recording from microphone.

But this example does not work.

`file` is an mp3 file.

When i pass it into `bytes` my result is ab empty string `""`

Comment: I have no idea but ... hi Gates, when will you buy AWS?

Comment: @FranxiHidro until bezos gets vaccined so i can activate the microbots

Answer (score 0):

I guess i got it.

```
let buffer = await file.arrayBuffer()
let context = new AudioContext()
context.decodeAudioData(buffer, async res => {
    let output = res.getChannelData(0)
    await Predictions.convert({
        transcription: {
            source: {
                bytes: output

            }
        }
    }).then(({ transcription: { fullText } }) => console.log({ fullText }))
})
```

You need to use `AudioContext`. You decode your buffer and then get the channelData and pass this into your transcription